# react formik listen changes for nested array prop object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I am using formik and my form schema is like this

```
const FormSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  id: Yup.number(),
  myNumber: Yup.number(),
  name: Yup.string().required("Required"),
  products: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
      productName: Yup.string().required('Product Name is required').min(3, "Minimum 3 characters required."),
      supplier: Yup.string().nullable(),
      basePrice: Yup.number().required("Required").positive("Should be greater than 0"),
      rentPrice: Yup.number().required("Required").positive("Should be greater than 0"),
    })
  ),

});
```

now there can be multiple products , and every product having `basePrice`. I want to listen the changes if there is change in `basePrice` for any product, and based on that i am updating `rentPrice`

```
useEffect(() => {
    
}, [formikAgreementForm.values.products]);
```

something like this but only on `basePrice`

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can achieve this by modified changes in '**useEffect**' and checking for changes in the '**basePrice**' of any product.**

updated code:

```
const { values, setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();

useEffect(() => {

  const productBasePriceChanged = values.products.some((product, index) => {

    const currentBasePrice = values.products[index].basePrice;
    const previousBasePrice = formikAgreementForm.values.products[index].basePrice; 

    return currentBasePrice !== previousBasePrice;
  });

  if (productBasePriceChanged) {
    const updatedProducts = values.products.map((product) => ({
      ...product,
      rentPrice: calculateRentPrice(product.basePrice), 
    }));

    setFieldValue('products', updatedProducts);
  }

}, [values.products, formikAgreementForm.values.products, setFieldValue]);



const calculateRentPrice = (basePrice) => {
    return basePrice * 5 //({5} => it should be anything depend on your calculations); 
  };
```